# database design storing historical information

Tags: sql-server

I have this database table Templates and I need to keep historical information. So in code what I am doing is inserting a new row with the updated data and then setting the  IsCurrentVersion flag to false. This is working fine but I am not sure how this will grow. Will that have performance problems? Is there a better way to do this? would a archive table be better?

```
Table Templates {
  id int [pk]
  Title varchar
  Added datetime
  Moddified datatime
  Deleted datetime
  IsCurrentVersion bit
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check out Temporal Tables https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a bit for IsCurrentVersion, I'd suggest setting up a version table and then use queries that let you pick the max version. I have several examples of the necessary code [in this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/sql-strategies-for-versioned-data/). This method performs extremely well and has scaled well over time. However, [there are alternatives](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-training/yet-another-sql-strategy-for-versioned-data/) that also work well. Between these two methods, you should be able to do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: on the pre-calculated column IsLastVersion why are the modifications slower? I understand why it is fast.

Comment: Testing will always be your friend here. I would expect, depending on how you set up the queries, that the IsCurrentVersion will yield poor row counts in the stats, leading to scans for the data.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2016 and later have a feature called Temporal Tables. These will keep change history and give you tools to query historical values at any point in time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15